# CakePHP not inserting CSRF tokens in postlink

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and for my logout "button" I'm using a postlink. Unless I unlock the logout action, I get a blackhole response. Cake doesn't appear to be adding CSRF tokens the way it does for regular forms when the security component is enabled.

This is on my default view in the header.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Log Out'), array('action' => 'logout', 'controller' => 'users'), null, __('Are you sure you want to log out?'));
```

Here is what it generates

```
<form action="/users/logout" name="post_531cbd2c9a3b6464512218" id="post_531cbd2c9a3b6464512218" style="display:none;" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?')) { document.post_531cbd2c9a3b6464512218.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Log Out</a>
```

When I print the request token of the _validateCsrf method of SecurityComponent.php nothing is displayed.

```
protected function _validateCsrf(Controller $controller) {

    $token = $this->Session->read('_Token'); //if I print this, it shows other tokens
    $requestToken = $controller->request->data('_Token.key');

    pr($requestToken); //nothing is displayed
    die();

    if (isset($token['csrfTokens'][$requestToken]) && $token['csrfTokens'][$requestToken] >= time()) {
        if ($this->csrfUseOnce) {
            $this->Session->delete('_Token.csrfTokens.' . $requestToken);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how postlink security is handled? Is the blackhole being caused by the lack of tokens, or am I not doing something else?

**Edit - I figured it out. Pretty obvious!**

Because the link is generated for the header on my default layout, that link isn't really tied to any particular controller. That same header is used whether I'm in the UsersController or PostsController. So, if security isn't enabled on the UsersController and I happen to be on a view for a UsersController action, the tokens won't appear. If I'm in the AdminsController which has security enabled, the tokens will appear.

Comment: You are not mistaken.  Normally with the security component on, post links will generate an additional hidden input for the token.  I cannot say though what is going in wrong in your case.

Comment: @Kai I figured it out. I updated my post

Comment: @user1104854 - You can post solution as an answer rather than adding it in a question.